# django custom model field

Tags: django, django-models

If I have 2 interlinked models:

```
class Person(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()

class Project(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    title = models.CharField()
```

I frequently find myself trying to find the number of Projects associated with each Person:

```
person = Person.objects.get(id=1)
no_projects = Project.objects.filter(person=person).count()
```

Is there a way of adding this as a custom field to the Person model, such that I may just call `person.no_projects`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by adding a property to the Person class.

```
class Person(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()

    @property
    def no_projects(self):
        return Project.objects.filter(person=self).count()
```

This can be called now like this

```
person = Person.objects.get(id=1)
person.no_projects
```

Answer (score 4):

In fact, that functionality is (almost) built-in. Instead of querying Projects, you can just do `person.project_set.count()` to get that person's count of projects (and `.all()` to get the actual list).

Comment: thank you, didn't know about this. How would this compare in efficiency to the marked answer, or do they both call a single count() query?

Comment: They evaluate to the same SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property() to generate the dynamical field.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    title = models.CharField()

    def _get_no_projects(self):
        return Projects.objects.filter(person=self).count()

    no_projects = property(_get_no_projects)
```

But the dynamical fields can not be used in querying, because the they don't really store data into the database.

FYI: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/aug/18/django-tips-using-properties-models-and-managers/